# WP7 how to store LiveConnectSession during TombStoning?

Tags: windows-phone-7, tombstoning, windows-live

I'm using the windows live sign in strategy of the PhotoSkyOnTheGo example provided by MS. So when my app starts, it shows a windows live sign in page.

During app runtime I remember the LiveConnectSession to connect to SkyDrive.

Now when the app tombstones, I need a way to save the LiveConnectSession. IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings does not work, probably because the LiveConnectSession is not serializable (it shows some InvalidDataContractException in the debug output).

So how do I store the Session in case the app tombstones? Or is the provided PhotoSkyOnTheGo-example rubbish and I need to be able to reconnect anytime I'm accessing SkyDrive?

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses `wl.offline_access` scope than the `live:SignInButton` control saves it for you and loads it automatically. Just use the `SessionChanged` event to capture the session object. This way the user will need to sign in only once.

Scope:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243646.aspx#wlofflineaccess

Event:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/microsoft.live.controls.signinbutton.sessionchanged.aspx