# Store LiveConnectSession in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to use the Hotmail API on my Windows Phone 7 App. Therefore, I have to grant access to my mobile app. I do that using the [Microsoft Live Connect API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/live/ff621314), which really works great for the start. I use the following code for authentication:

```
string[] requiredScope = { "wl.signin", "wl.calendars_update", "wl.offline_access" };
LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient(Configuration.ClientID);
auth.LoginCompleted += new EventHandler<LoginCompletedEventArgs>(authInitializeCompletedHandler);
auth.LoginAsync(requiredScope);
```

ClientID is the ID I got from MS for registering my app. My callback looks (in simple) like this:

```
private void authInitializeCompletedHandler(object sender, LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
    {
        this._session = e.Session; // Session hat AccessToken und RefreshToken
        this._isAuthorized = true;
        callDelegates();
    }
}
```

If that call succeeds (and it currently does, so that works), I store the retrieved Session. This session can be used in the LiveConnectClient constructor to enable the communication with the MS API's, in my app the Hotmail API.

```
LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(_session);
```

My problem is that I want to save that session somehow, so that when the app is tombstoned and gets its focus back, I don't want the user to ask again for permission - he already gave me that. I have figured out by myself that the returned session contains a AccessToken, RefreshToken and Expires property (I know what that is, that's not the problem). How can I use that information in future calls? Microsoft's documentation about that ends here and I can't find any useful information.

2 workarounds I found:

- [Live Connect Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946629/wp7-how-to-store-liveconnectsession-during-tombstoning): Should not be the way to go, because I don't want to show the Live Button just that I get my session variable back.
- [RESTful API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243649.aspx): This would require that I completely rewrite what I have done so far because everything relies on the LiveConnectClient (which makes communication pretty easy).

But I don't really want to use that workarounds. I believe/hope that there is a better solution.

Comment: I know what you mean, man. Some of the bizarre/arbitrary restrictions Microsoft puts on their APIs are frustrating. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the answer to this is as follows

> 1. Make sure you applications include both wl.signin and wl.offline_access scopes.
> 2. If you're not using the signin control provided in the SDK, you should always call LiveAuthClient.InitializeAsync when the app starts.
>      Only call LiveAuthClient.LoginAsync if InitializeAsync does not return
>      a valid session.
>
> These steps will ensure you receiving a refresh token so no need to
>   prompt for login or consent after the first time.

From:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/6df1f31d-a22c-469c-b9f4-5c79e0882701