# How do i create an instance of LiveConnectClient?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

```
LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient();   // ERROR
```

`LiveConnectClient` constructor requires a `LiveConnectSession` varaiable but `LiveConnectSession` doesn't have a public constructor and a reference can not even be assigned without initializing.

How do i fix the above error?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the previous bad answer; I was assuming too much. So the error just means that you aren't meant to create a LiveConnectClient that way.

See [this Microsoft post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243649.aspx) for some example code and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726042/store-liveconnectsession-in-wp7) which has some similar code.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/microsoft.live.liveconnectsession

No, it is not a abstract class.

Comment: Yes Jason, Your second link is quite helpful. Hope it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

LiveConnectClient needs to be created with a valid LiveConnectSession as you found out. This is intended to be used with the SignInButton from the Live SDK. After you install the Live SDK, add a SignInButton to your XAML and handle the SessionChanged event in your code behind.

The LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs parameter included in the SessionChanged event contains the LiveConnectSession that you can use to create the LiveConnectClient. Simply keep that Session for the lifetime of your application.

Cheers
Laurent