# Get a file from OneDrive and use data of xml file into C# application

Tags: c#, xml, dotnet-httpclient, onedrive, live-sdk

I have place a xml file online on OneDrive and shared whit everyone that use my program. Now I want to read this into my C# application. I have try a lot of code. A list below:

1. I have try whit a `HttpClient` and a `HttpResponseMessage`. But it give me the html code from the webpage of OneDrive. I understand why if you look to the page.

   [image: OneDrive file on onedrive.live.com]
2. I have also looking for to use LiveSDK in my application whit the following code:

   ```
   try
   {
       LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.session);
       LiveOperationResult operationResult = await liveClient.GetAsync(@"https://onedrive.live.com/?****");
       dynamic result = operationResult.Result;
   }
   catch (LiveConnectException ex)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine("LiveConnectException catched => " + ex.Message);
   }
   ```

   But I can't create an instance of `LiveConnectClient` because you need to log in and I don't want that. Found on this links: "[Working with Microsoft OneDrive folders and files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826531.aspx)" on MSDN and "[Store LiveConnectSession in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726042/store-liveconnectsession-in-wp7)" on Stackoverflow.

Can anyone help me or explain it? I need only the xml code (not the html code) and will make a graph of the data. I use the language C# for load the file. *Sorry for my bad english or some mistakes, I'm new with Microsoft Live accounts and access in into an application.*

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a single file that you'd just like your clients to be able to download, you'll just want to assemble a variant on the sharing link that you received from the share UI, which should look like this:

```
https://onedrive.live.com/redir
?resid=8bf6ae9dbc6caa4c!116505
&authkey=!AD0q0bcg_i3dmvg
&ithint=file%2ctxt
```

You will want to modify the path from **redir** into **download**, and you can removed the **ithint** parameter so the request looks like the following:

```
https://onedrive.live.com/download.aspx
?resid=8bf6ae9dbc6caa4c%216505
&authkey=%21AD0q0bcg_i3dmvg
```

This url should allow you to make an anonymous request and download that shared file for your applications usage.

For more robust sharing scenarios, I'd recommend looking at https://dev.onedrive.com for a list of all supported scenarios with examples on how to use them